# Spring JPA Save Method - Performance Issue

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have one performance problem in JPA save() method. I Have "CustomerHistory" Table it's like a log table I'm not even use this table data in my application. (I'm not perform any get query operations in the table). But If I save the "CustomerHistory" Model using JPA Save Method Means it's every time return the CustomerHistory Model After saving the data. So I need to know if it's play the big role in performance?

```
 public CustomerHistory saveCustomerHistoryLog(CustomerHistory  customerHistory ){
    return customerHistoryRepository.save(customerHistory );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced a similar issue because of providing the `@Id` value generated in the application code.

Please make sure that the primary key column annotated with `@Id` should be null and generated using `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`. Then JPA consider it as a new record.

If you provide the primary key column in the code, then JPA consider it as update so it will do a fetch for doing the update/insert based on the fetch result. In that case there may be a latency.

If all you are doing with that table is inserting the record, then provide the `@Id` column as null and auto generated.

Answer (score 2):

If the `CustomerHistory` does not have any relationship to other entities , it should be okay.

But even if it has relationship to other entities , and if you are following the best practice that do not enable eager fetching when mapping the related entities , it should not affect the performance since they are lazy loaded and no unnecessary SQL will be triggered to load them if you do not access them.

Answer (score 0):

Here i found some there ways to improve performance in jpa save method:

[Improve JPA Save Method Performances](https://medium.com/@sridharmcakec/refactor-jpa-save-method-to-improve-application-performance-b7a77db2794c)

Comment: Please avoid adding paywalled articles. Medium is now mostly paywalled and it's not possible to view the answers anymore